# How to use Docker swarm DNS/Service names in Nginx upstream

Tags: nginx, docker, dns, routes, docker-swarm

I have a service running across 4 swarm nodes (ServiceA) and a Nginx service running across 4 nodes on the same Swarm.  The Nginx service exposes/publishes ports 80 and 443.  All the services are connected to the same user-defined overlay network and most importantly I can curl/ping the service name (ServiceA) from within the containers so all is working so far.

My question is how do I get Nginx upstream to work with the service names? I've read a lot and tried adding this to the nginx.conf `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;` but it has not helped and the Nginx service will not start.  Any ideas on how to get Nginx see the Docker network DNS names?

This is my nginx.conf

```
events { 
    worker_connections 4096; 
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/conf/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    proxy_send_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;

    upstream serviceA {
        ip_hash;
        server serviceA:8081;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
        keepalive_timeout  5 5;
        proxy_buffering    off;
        underscores_in_headers on;

        location ~ ^/serviceA(?<section>.*) {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log nginx_proxy_upstream;
            proxy_pass http://serviceA/$section$is_args$query_string;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
        keepalive_timeout  5 5;
        proxy_buffering    off;
        underscores_in_headers on;

        # allow large uploads
        client_max_body_size 10G;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myKey.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myKey.key;

        location ~ ^/serviceA(?<section>.*) {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log nginx_proxy_upstream;
            proxy_pass http://serviceA/$section$is_args$query_string;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `--link`? Creating a link results in a friendly name that will be resolvable from inside the containers.

Comment: I'm using docker swarm (17.03.1-ce). Can that be done using swarm. I don't see anything mention --link in the swarm documentation

Comment: Try to remove resolver.

Comment: Tried that, nginx service wont spin up 0/1 replicas.  Is there any way to see error logs for Docker swarm so I can see the exact reason why it fails to start.  I'm 99% sure its because it cant find the upstream serviceA.

Comment: @JulioHM links don't work in docker swarm anymore: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing the `resolver` should work if the upstream containers have already been deployed (DNS entries created). However this means that you cannot start nginx unless the upstream containers are already running.

For a *dynamic* approach via `resolver`, you need to make docker engine host's DNS accessible from within the container **(<s>not via `127.0.0.11` ... which is the container itself</s> UPDATE: on custom networks it is possible to query 127.0.0.0/8 addresses)**.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/ :

> Note: If you need access to a host’s localhost resolver, you must modify your **DNS service on the host to listen on a non-localhost address** that is reachable from within the container.

**UPDATE:**
I managed to do it on a custom overlay network in docker swarm like this:

```
  location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    set $upstream_addr <swarm_stack_name>:<port>;
    proxy_pass https://$upstream_addr;
    ...
  }
```

I did not get it to work with the `upstream {}` nginx directive ... this does not seem to handle dynamic resolves or I overlooked something.

Comment: Custom networks 127.0.0.11 still works (for me anyway)